# Join all lines with tabs inserted (vim)

Tags: vim, tabs

I have a tab delimited file (one line). I can easily enough replace the tabs with new lines so that I can see what fields are in what position

```
:%s/\t/\r/g
```

How can I do the inverse, after I've edited the fields? I could record a macro:

```
Js<tab>Esc
```

And then repeat it all the way down - but is there an easier way?

Comment: See this question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4148/can-i-join-lines-with-a-comma-or-another-character

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this:

```
:%s/\n/\t/
```

Comment: I was surprised that this actually works. I had no idea that `\n` would do anything at all in a :substitute command's regex.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `s` to replace newlines with tabs, basically the reverse of the operation you used to replace the tabs with newlines:

```
:%s/\n/\t/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:1,$-1s/$/\t/|%j
```

Which means: 
from the first line to the punultimate   `1,$-1`
replace the end of the line with a tab   `s/$/\t/`
and then    `|`
for all lines   `%`
join them   `j`